# How to swipe through 3 or more points using ADB?

Tags: python, android, adb

I'm trying to make a script to play a game called "Words of Wonder" which involves swiping through letters on the screen to fill a crossword.

[image: like this]

i tried

```
adb shell  "input touchscreen swipe x1 y1 x2 y2 & input command touchscreen swipe x2 y2 x3 y3"
```

but it resulted two swipes instead of one continuous swipe

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25500567/is-it-possible-to-produce-continuous-swipe-action-on-the-touchscreen-with-adb lease try https://stackoverflow.com/a/25500914/150978

Comment: @Robert getevent method wont work for my use case because it's not feasible for me to simulate all possible swipe combinates and save the getevent data individually. Ideally i want a method which swipes through 3 points with coordinates (x1, y1) (x2, y2) and (x3, y3)

Comment: The getevent data doesn't seem too complicated, so generating them instead of recording may be feasible (or recording and simplyfying them). https://stackoverflow.com/q/12280657/150978

Comment: Check https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/discussions/310